# Visual Studio 2013 Web Deploy Package Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, webdeploy

I've been using the Web Deploy Package to publish a site I'm working on to our test server but for some reason its started including the .sln file and it doesn't seem to be compiling the solution anymore. I've checked the configuration and its using the release build but when I deploy all of the .cs and .designer.cs are included. I'm deploying a second site using the same setting and that is deploying OK.

Has anyone else experienced this? I've cleaned and rebuilt the solution and I've deleted the publish profile and created a new one but nothing has helped.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this now. It turns out in the project properties > Package/Publish Web Tab I had the Items to deploy drop down set to "All files in this project". I changed to "Only files needed to run this application" and everything worked as expected.